# FormulaArray produces error 1004 and error 424

Tags: excel, vba

When trying to use an array formula I was getting:

> Error 1004: "Unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class"

Research indicated that it was because my formula was too long, so I tried a "Replace" trick described by others.

I now get:

> Runtime error '424': "Object required"

on my first `.Replace` line.

```vb
For k = LastRow + 4 To LastRow + 3 + KeyListIndex
    FormulaArrayString = "=MIN(IF('" & KeyDataRange & "='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'" & DateDataRange & "))"
    With Sheets(DataFindingsTab).Cells(k, 2).FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF('KeyDataRange='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'DateDataRange))"
        .Replace "KeyDataRange", TabName & " '!$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
        .Replace "DateDataRange", TabName & " '!$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
    End With
Next k
```

Variable `FormulaArrayString` is in there to check my work, and watching it confirms that it matches the working array formula lin my worksheet.

Update: I've fixed the newline issue and also a few errant spaces I noticed, so now my code looks like this but I'm still getting the error:

```vb
    For k = LastRow + 4 To LastRow + 3 + KeyListIndex
      FormulaArrayString = "=MIN(IF('" & KeyDataRange & "='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'" & DateDataRange & "))"
      With Sheets(DataFindingsTab).Cells(k, 2)
        .FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF('KeyDataRange='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'DateDataRange))"
        .Replace "KeyDataRange", TabName & "'!$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
        .Replace "DateDataRange", TabName & "'!$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
      End With
    Next k
```

Is there a way to directly watch what's being passed to `.FormulaArray` so I can make certain it is what it is supposed to be?

The formula I'm aiming for is:

`=MIN(IF('1| Labor'!$B$2:$B$585='BOE Post-DoD Data Findings'!$A14,'1| Labor'!$E$2:$E$585))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a newline before the `.FormulaArray`

```
For k = LastRow + 4 To LastRow + 3 + KeyListIndex
  FormulaArrayString = "=MIN(IF('" & KeyDataRange & "='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'" & DateDataRange & "))"
  With Sheets(DataFindingsTab).Cells(k, 2)
    .FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF('KeyDataRange='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",'DateDataRange))"
    .Replace "KeyDataRange", TabName & " '!$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
    .Replace "DateDataRange", TabName & " '!$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
  End With
Next k
```

...but your formula looks off on that line (missing an ending `'` ?)

Comment: What a silly thing to miss (the newline)... I think I had been staring at it for too long :) However, I fixed that and I'm getting the same error. The lack of a closing ```'``` does look a bit odd, but you can see it's contained in the second ```.Replace``` line in the section ```"'!$"``` (although I did notice there were extra spaces just now... I removed those and I'm still getting the error).

Comment: You still need to be able to set a valid formula in the first place - if the inserted formula is not valid then it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I had forgotten something I read when about using `.Replace` to shorten array formulas--the shortened version with your placeholders still needs to be syntactically correct. Tim Williams' question about the closing `'` actually was part of the issue--even though everything looked OK once the `.Replace`s were done, Excel didn't like that what I was putting into `.ArrayFormula` wasn't syntactically correct.

Here's the code that works:

```vb
    For k = LastRow + 4 To LastRow + 3 + KeyListIndex
      With Sheets(DataFindingsTab).Cells(k, 2)
        .FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(KeyDataRange='" & DataFindingsTab & "'!$A" & CStr(k) & ",DateDataRange))"
        .Replace "KeyDataRange", "'" & TabName & "'!$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(KeyCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
        .Replace "DateDataRange", "'" & TabName & "'!$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$2:$" & Number2Letter(DateCol) & "$" & CStr(LastDetailRow)
      End With
    Next k
```